# Show the column required of a table using group by function in oracle

Tags: oracle, group-by, subquery

I want to display the column c.officeID along with the column "Amount". This is my query:

```
select  c.officeID,max(Sum(p.amount)) as “Amount” from payment p, client c where c.clientid in (select clientid from client) and p.clientID=c.clientID group by c.officeID;
```

I tried using:

```
select  c.officeID,max(Sum(p.amount)) as “Amount” from payment p, client c where c.clientid in (select clientid from client) and p.clientID=c.clientID group by c.officeID,p.amount;
```

But I am getting a error saying 'ORA00937-Not a single group-group funtion'. Could anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a max and group by, use this following query to get the result, if you want max then use the second query,

```
SCOTT@research 17-APR-15> select c.empno,Sum(p.sal) as "Amount"
  2    from empp p, emp c
  3   where c.empno in (select empno from emp)
  4     and p.empno = c.empno
  5   group by c.empno
  6  ;

     EMPNO     Amount
---------- ----------
      7782       2450
      7839       5000
      7844       1500
      7698       2850
      7521       1250
      7902       3000
      7566       2975
      7654       1250
      7788       3000
      7934       1300
      7499       1600
      7876       1100
       234        800
      7900        950

14 rows selected.


select max("Amount") from (
select c.empno,Sum(p.sal) as "Amount"
  from empp p, emp c
 where c.empno in (select empno from emp)
   and p.empno = c.empno
 group by c.empno) 



MAX("AMOUNT")
-------------
         5000
```